# Applying axioms about Sequents

Tags: isabelle

Consider the following minimal development based on the Isabelle Sequents library:

```
theory Test
  imports Pure Sequents.Sequents
begin

syntax "_Trueprop"    :: "two_seqe" ("((_)/ ⊢ (_))" [6,6] 5)
consts Trueprop :: two_seqi
parse_translation ‹[  (@{syntax_const "_Trueprop"}, K (two_seq_tr @{const_syntax Trueprop}))  ]›
print_translation ‹[  (@{const_syntax Trueprop}, K (two_seq_tr' @{syntax_const "_Trueprop"}))  ]›

axiomatization where
  identity : "$A, P, $B ⊢ $C, P, $D" and
  xch : "$A, $B, $C, $D, $E ⊢ $F  ⟹  $A, $D, $C, $B, $E ⊢ $F"

lemma xch0 : "$A, $B, $D, $E ⊢ $F  ⟹  $A, $D, $B, $E ⊢ $F"
  apply (rule xch ; assumption)  done

lemma xch1 : "$A, $B, P, $D, $E ⊢ $F  ⟹  $A, $D, P, $B, $E ⊢ $F"
  apply (rule xch ; assumption)  done

lemma xch2 : "$A, $B, P1, P2, $D, $E ⊢ $F  ⟹  $A, $D, P1, P2, $B, $E ⊢ $F"
  apply (rule xch ; assumption)  done
```

The attempted proofs of the lemmas fail.  However, they succeed if I remove the `identity` axiom!  So my first question is, why does the presence of the `identity` axiom affect these proofs that don't use it?

My main question is how to make these proofs work when I do have the identity axiom.  My guess is that I need to explicitly specialize the variables, such as by applying `xch[of A B _ D E F]`.  This seems like the right specialization (it works in the absence of `identity`), but it gives a very strange error

```
Failed to meet type constraint:
Term   A :: 'a => seq'
Type   seq' => seq'
```

Do I need to write something explicit in place of the `_`?  If so, what?  I can't figure out how to explicitly write "the empty sequence" or "the sequence containing only `P`" or "the sequence containing only `P1, P2`" — the magic-ness of the `$A` notation is defeating me.

**Edit:** Andreas's answer to my first question solves my actual problem completely, so I am renaming this question and accepting that answer.  But I would still like to know the answer to my second question, so I'm re-asking it separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50825490/780077).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message for the explicit instantiation of the variables already indicates that something with the types is wrong. The problem is that `axiomatization` calls the type inference on all axioms at the same time. Since the `identity` axiom uses the same variable name `A`  as the `xch` axiom, type inference assigns them the same type. If the `identity` axiom is not there, type inference computes a more general type, which makes the proofs work. Consequently, there are two ways to avoid this problem:

1. Use different variable names in all axioms mentioned in an `axiomatization` block. This does the trick, but it usually reduces readability and it is easy to overlook something.
2. Avoid free variables in the axioms by explicitly quantifying them using Pure's meta quantifier.

In your example, approach 2 would look like this:

```
axiomatization where
  identity : "⋀A P B C D. $A, P, $B ⊢ $C, P, $D" and 
  xch : "⋀A B C D E F. $A, $B, $C, $D, $E ⊢ $F  ⟹  $A, $D, $C, $B, $E ⊢ $F"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea what that warning message meant.  I will certainly do it your second way from now on, that is clearly the right way.  However, I would like to understand better what goes wrong.  I did realize that all occurrences of the same (unbound) variable in `axiomatization` get the same type, but it didn't occur to me that that might be the problem, since intuitively in both axioms `A` has the same type, namely "a list of propositions".  Presumably this has something to do with the implementation of the `$`-magic of the Sequents theory; can you explain it?

Comment: Also, why can all the supplied theories that use `Sequents` get away without explicit meta-quantifiers?   Like https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/Sequents/Sequents/LK0.html and https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/Sequents/Sequents/ILL.html.

Comment: Yes, this is all about the `$`-magic. If all variables in sequent statement use `$`, then type inference will produce a more general type for the variables, namely `'a => 'a` instead of `seq => seq`. So, instead of making your axioms more general, you could also have made the types in your lemma more specialized by explicitly declaring the types of the variables, e.g., using `for A B D E F :: seq => seq`.If you look closely at the other theories about `Sequents`, you will see that none of the lemmas there use only `$`-ized variables. Therefore, they never run into the polymorphism problem.

Comment: This indicates that your `xch` axiom might actually be too general.