# Instantiating axioms about Sequents explicitly

Tags: isabelle

**Note:** This is a re-asking of the second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50816231/780077), which turned out to be less related to the first question (answered there) than I thought it would.

Consider the following minimal development based on the Isabelle Sequents library:

```
theory Test
  imports Pure Sequents.Sequents
begin

syntax "_Trueprop"    :: "two_seqe" ("((_)/ ⊢ (_))" [6,6] 5)
consts Trueprop :: two_seqi
parse_translation ‹[  (@{syntax_const "_Trueprop"}, K (two_seq_tr @{const_syntax Trueprop}))  ]›
print_translation ‹[  (@{const_syntax Trueprop}, K (two_seq_tr' @{syntax_const "_Trueprop"}))  ]›

axiomatization where
  xch : "⋀A B C D. $A, $B, $C ⊢ $D  ⟹  $C, $B, $A ⊢ $D"

lemma xch0 : "$A, $C ⊢ $D  ⟹  $C, $A ⊢ $D"
  apply (rule xch[of A _ C D] ; assumption)  done

lemma xch1 : "$A, P, $C ⊢ $D  ⟹  $C, P, $A ⊢ $D"
  apply (rule xch[of A _ C D] ; assumption)  done

lemma xch2 : "$A, P, Q, $C ⊢ $D  ⟹  $C, P, Q, $A ⊢ $D"
  apply (rule xch[of A _ C D] ; assumption)  done
```

These proofs work (in fact, they work even without the `of` annotations).  However, I want to know what I could write in place of the `_`s to be maximally explicit.  That is, how do I write "the empty sequence" or "the sequence containing only `P`" or "the sequence containing only `P, Q`"?  It doesn't work to write `""` for `xch0`, nor `P` or `"P"` for `xch1`, nor `"P, Q"` for `xch2`, and I can't figure out from the source of `Sequents` what explicit syntax these notations are abbreviations for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequences on the left hand side of `⊢` are internally represented as function applications. This ensures that higher-order unification can instantiate schematic variables in theorems with arbitrarily many consecutive elements. So `$A, $B, $C ⊢ $D` are interally represented as `Trueprop (%s. A (B (C s))) (%s. D s)`.

So in your first lemma, `B` gets instantiated by the identity function `%x. x`.

Individual elements of object type `o` are transformed into this applicative format using the constant `SeqO'` and `Seq1'` declared at the start of the `Sequents` theory.
The `$` marker indicates that the parser should not insert such a constant.

So in your second lemma, `B` is instantiated with `SeqO'(P)`. In the third lemma, `B` must be instantiated with the sequence of `P` and `Q`, which is expressed represented by `%s. SeqO'(P, SeqO'(Q, s))`. The notations `<<P>>` and `<<P, Q>>` denote the same and are preferable.

You can look at the internal representation of a sequent using Isabelle/ML via

```
ML {* @term{"$A, P, $C ⊢ $D"} *}
```

That's how I figured out what was going on.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  It looks like I can also write `<< >>` in the first lemma.